# Jquery menu replace

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I have a cakePhp project. There, I have a header file which contains two menus, one for web and one for mobile. But both are same. Now my SEO says, he does not want duplicate URLs in the code as Google creates problem for this.

What are the ways?

One I can put both menus in different .ctp files and replace them dynamically. If yes, then how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having duplicate urls for SEO purposes relates to having two different urls which serve the same content. It has nothing to do with duplication of `<a>` tags within your markup.

If you wanted to make them appear or disappear I would recommend making them into elements and then doing a check in your layout for a mobile browser and swapping them accordingly.

Comment: I have header.ctp in View/Elements. And script.js is doing display on and off by checking browser. But still, menu which is not displaying is there with display off attribute and google crawled it. can you explain exact solution.